# Flutter How to resolve couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority and Conflict with other plugins about FileProvider?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-fileprovider

Actually i'm using `open_file` and `flutter_webview_plugin packages` in same project.
While running the application am getting error like:-

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.fileprovider`

Then i found a document to add the provider to solve this issue, so i have added in `Androidmanifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
package="com.example">
...
<application>
...
       <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
                tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider> 

</application>
```

After adding this provider also am getting same error. In both packages they are using fileProvider. Hence it is getting conflicts.

***so, help me out to configure both packages fileProvider.***

```
dependencies:
  open_file: ^3.0.1
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.11
```

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 1):

Yea after a whole day surfing i have resloved this issue, 
Use Custom file Provider to avoid collision with other plugins, such as `open_file`.

In `flutter_webview_plugin` follow these below steps to resolve it.

Step : 1

In `android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

remove

```
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
```

add

```
android:name="com.flutter_webview_plugin.FlutterWebviewPluginFileProvider"
```

Step : 2

In `android/src/main/java/com/flutter_webview_plugin/FlutterWebviewPluginFileProvider.java`

create new class `FlutterWebviewPluginFileProvider.java`

```
package com.flutter_webview_plugin;

import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

public class FlutterWebviewPluginFileProvider extends FileProvider {

}
```

Step : 3

In `android/src/main/java/com/flutter_webview_plugin/WebviewManager.java`

remove import

```
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
```

find and remove this line

```
return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, packageName + ".fileprovider", capturedFile);
```

add this

```
return FlutterWebviewPluginFileProvider.getUriForFile(context, packageName + ".fileprovider", capturedFile);
```

`Refered by :` https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/commit/aeda1e80effd59afdb526b11608cb232a83a6bab

Thanks