# FLUTTER - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.mypackage.flutter.share_provider

Tags: flutter, android-manifest, flutter-dependencies

sorry, i want to ask how to solve this case
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.mypackage.flutter.share_provider

this happen when i add this code in androidmanifest (from folder android)

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
                tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>
```

i add this code because i use "flutter_webview_plugin" (if im not add this code in my android manifest, there is one error such as androidx)

my full error:

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.mypackage.flutter.share_provider
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:662)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:635)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:441)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at io.flutter.plugins.share.SharePlugin.shareFile(SharePlugin.java:102)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at io.flutter.plugins.share.SharePlugin.onMethodCall(SharePlugin.java:48)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6841)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share(19541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/flutter (19541): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.mypackage.flutter.share_provider, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority id.co.ajsmsig.cosmos.orion.dev.flutter.share_provider
E/flutter (19541):  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:662)
E/flutter (19541):  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:635)
E/flutter (19541):  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:441)
E/flutter (19541):  at io.flutter.plugins.share.SharePlugin.shareFile(SharePlugin.java:102)
E/flutter (19541):  at io.flutter.plugins.share.SharePlugin.onMethodCall(SharePlugin.java:48)
E/flutter (19541):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (19541):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter (19541):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/flutter (19541):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (19541):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/flutter (19541):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
E/flutter (19541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6841)
E/flutter (19541):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (19541):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/flutter (19541):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this topic answer, seems to be related:

[Flutter How to resolve couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority and Conflict with other plugins about FileProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61811416/9580935)

Comment: sorry, i already try this, and still got the same error

Comment: There's also this: [Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61811416/9580935)